# 401 Error on Android Push Notification from Azure Website

Tags: android, windows, azure, push-notification

I have a php script on my Windows Azure website that sends push notifications to Android devices. In Google Cloud Console. When I set to allow all IP's. It works just fine, but when I set it to only allow my Azure Website by putting in the public IP it gives me a 401. Do I suppose to provide the Public IP of the server? If not how do I get the right IP to allow access?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying your Azure VIP(Virtual IP) as allowed IP.
You get your VIP by calling the [Get Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx) Service Management API.
Ref to Doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433027.aspx)

Comment: Thanks let me try that @spidergears.

Comment: I don't have any cloud services I just have a website. Anyway you can give me a step by step process. I just want a VIP.